# Программа с двумя режимами

Tags: freepascal

Доброго вечера!
Нужно составить программу для решения данной системы при помощи двух режимов

```
M=max(A,B,C)
Y=(система)
2x-k x<0
e+xk 0<=x<=2
lnx-k x>2
```

Программу написала, но неуверенна в правильности

```
Var
  A,B,C,max,cz,x,k:integer;
  e,y:real;
begin
  e:=2,7
  write ('Введите что нужно найти 1. число max, 2 уравнение');
  readln(cz);
  case (cz) Of
    1:
    begin
      write('Введите А:');
      readln (A);
      write('Введите В:');
      readln(B);
      write('Введите С:');
      readln (C);
      max:=A;
      if (max<C) then max:=C;
      if (max<B) then max:=B;
      writeln ('Число max=',max);
    end;
    2:
    begin
      write ('Введите х');
      readln (x);
      write ('Введите k');
      readln (k);
      if x<=0
        then y:=2x-k
      else if
        (0<=x) and (x<=2)
      then y:= e+xk
      else y:= Ln(x)-k
      Writeln('y=', y);
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: > Программу написала, но неуверенна в правильности

Запустите, проверьте.

Comment: На вскидку: 

 - `e:=2,7` - целая часть отделяется от дробной точкой, а не запятой, кроме того, не хватает точки с запятой в конце.
 - `y:=2x-k` и `y:= e+xk` - знак умножения пропущен.
 - `Ln(x)-k` - точка с  запятой в конце строки.